# Recognize when angular bootstrap dropdown-menu is closed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-bootstrap

Is there a way to recognize that angular-bootstrap dropdown-menu is closed?
I want to recognize this event and run specific function.

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Add to your parent div an on-toggle event

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" on-toggle="toggled(open)">
```

And handle it witin the controller

```
$scope.toggled = function(open) {
    if (open) {
        console.log('is open');
    } else console.log('close');
}
```

Comment: It's unbelivable that a such simple solution exists!

Comment: Also works with Angular Bootstrap (uib-dropdown). Had been searching for a while. Thanks!

Comment: Is there an Angular 2 update for the controller? New to Angular and trying to figure out what I'd do

Comment: @GREnvoy For Angular 2 you can use the openChange output of the dropdown directive: `<div ngbDropdown (openChange)="toggled($event)">` Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/biHtYi/